# Laptop Lid State Incorrect After Suspend and Resume - Causes Repeated Suspend

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, acpi, lid, resume

After installing updates on a clean install of Xubuntu 16.04, my laptop fails to completely resume after suspending by closing the lid.
This did work *before* installing the updates (i.e. on the completely clean install).

After receiving some help debugging the problem from folks on IRC, it turns out that the lid incorrectly reports as closed after resuming.

Example Repro:

1. Close lid to suspend
2. Open lid to reopen
3. Laptop will resume for a few seconds (not even long enough to show login), then immediately suspend again

Quickly switching to tty1 and running `cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state` after resuming shows the lid as closed.